# CellClick event and SelectionChanged event in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

What is the difference between the CellClick event and the  SelectionChanged event in the Windows Froms DataGridView control?

And when exactly is the selection changed event run: before the form load event or after?

Comment: You change the selection without clicking, e.g. by using the keyboard.

Comment: Also you can click cell without changing selection. Click with right button for example.

Answer (score 6):

The best reference for this sort of question is the MSDN DataGridView documentation.

For the [CellClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx) event they say:

> This event occurs when any part of a cell is clicked, including
>   borders and padding. It also occurs when the user presses and releases
>   the SPACE key while a button cell or check box cell has focus, and
>   will occur twice for these cell types if the cell is clicked while
>   pressing the SPACE key.

For the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx) event:

> This event occurs whenever cells are selected or the selection is
>   canceled, whether programmatically or by user action. For example,
>   this event is useful when you want display the sum of the currently
>   selected cells.

The obvious difference is that the CellClick can fire even when the DataGridView selection does not change, for example with a right click or when clicking on the currently selected cell. Also the selection can change without a cell being clicked, for example when you change the selection programatically.

As for when exactly the selection changed event is run in relation to the form load event, when attached in the form constructor it is before (and several times at that!).

I just proved that to myself with the following code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyBindingList<BackingObject> backing_objects = new MyBindingList<BackingObject>();
    backing_objects.Add(new BackingObject{ PrimaryKey = 1, Name  = "Fred", Hidden = "Fred 1"});          

    dataGridView1.DataSource = backing_objects;

    this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
}

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Load");
}

void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Selection Changed");            
}
```

The output window reads:

```
Selection Changed
Selection Changed
Selection Changed
Load
```

Note that you can make the selection changed fire **after** the load event by attaching it during the DataBindingComplete event handler.

```
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);

void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
}
```

Now in the output window you only see:

```
Load
```

And there is no selection changed output until the grid selection is changed (by for example a cell click)